Understanding the proof of the finiteness of the class number
The proof is in Chapter 12 of Rosen and Ireland's A Classical Introduction To Modern Number Theory. Proposition 12.2.3 states that $D/A$ is finite, where $D$ is the ring of all algebraic integers in a number field, and $A\subset D$ is an ideal. The equivalence relation $A\sim B$ means there exists $\alpha,\beta\in D$ such that $(\alpha)A=(\beta)B$. I've been stuck in the highlighted part for a long time:

How to use the proposition to show that $M!$ is contained in at most finitely many ideals?
Why $A\sim B$ with $B$ is one of at most finitely many ideals implies $h_F$ (the class number of $F$) is finite?

Any help will be appreciated.

Theorem.
The class number of $F$ is finite.


Proof.
Let $A$ be an ideal in $D$. For $\alpha \in A$, $\alpha \neq 0$, $|N(\alpha)|$ is a positive integer. Choose $\beta \in A$, $\beta \neq 0$, so that $|N(\beta)|$ is minimal. For any $\alpha \in A$ there is a $t$, $1 \leq t \leq M$, such that $|N(t\alpha - \omega\beta)| < |N(\beta)|$ with $\omega \in D$. Since $t\alpha - \omega\beta \in A$ we must have $t\alpha - \omega\beta = 0$. It follows that $M!A \subset (\beta)$. Let $B = (1/\beta)M!A \subset D$. $B$ is an ideal and $M!A = (\beta)B$. Since $\beta \in A$, $M!\beta \in (\beta)B$ and so $M! \in B$. By Proposition 12.2.3 $M!$ can be contained in at most finitely many ideals. We have shown $A \sim B$ where $B$ is one of at most finitely many ideals. Thus $h_F$ is finite, as asserted.



Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post. Here are the explanations why.

Suppose there are infinitely classes $\{[A_{i}]:i\in I\}$. Then for each class, choose a representative $A_{i}$, and construct $B_{i}=(1/\beta_{i})M! A_{i}$ in the same manner as the first paragraph of the image. Then $[B_{i}]=[A_{i}]$ for all $i\in I$ since $(\beta_{i})B_{i}=(M!)A_{i}$.
Note that $M!\in B_{i}$ for all $i$. Then for each $i\in I$, $D/B_{i}\subseteq D/(M!)$ which is a finite ring.
A finite ring has only finitely many subrings, hence $D/B_{i}=D/B_{j}$ for some $i\neq j$.
$\Rightarrow B_{i}=0+B_{i}=0+B_{j}=B_{j}$, contradicts to $[B_{i}]=[A_{i}]\neq[A_{j}]=[B_{j}]$.

When $M! \in B$ we have the containment of ideals $(M!) \subset B \subset D$. The ring $D/(M!)$ is finite, so it has finitely many ideals, and thus there are finitely many ideals between $(M!)$ and $D$.
Here is an analogous result: when $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup with finite index, there are finitely many subgroups of $G$ that contain $H$.
Step 1: prove this when $H = N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. The subgroups of $G$ that contain $N$ are in bijection with the subgroups of $G/N$, which is a finite group, so it has finitely many subgroups.
Step 2: $H$ is a general subgroup of finite index in $G$. There is a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ that is contained in $H$: let $G$ act by left multiplication on the finite set of left $H$-cosets $G/H$, which is a homomorphism $G \to {\rm Sym}(G/H)$ whose kernel is a normal subgroup with finite index that is a subset of $H$. By Step 1, there are finitely many subgroups of $G$ that contain $N$, and this finite set includes all subgroups of $G$ that contain $H$.
